# Replace Union All to join to improve performance

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, union-all

I have a working query which takes 20 mins to return data. I want to optimize it .
I have table

Incentives:

```
Transaction_ID | Incentive_On_A  | Incentive_On_B  | Incentive_On_C
--------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------
1             | 0               | 0               | 10
2             | 30              | 0               | 0
3             | 0               | 20              | 0
4             | 40              | 0               | 0
```

Required Output:

```
Transaction_ID| Product_Category | Incentive_Amt
 ----------   + -----------------+--------------
  1           | A                | 30
  2           | B                | 20
  3           | C                | 10
  4           | A                | 40
```

I am using this query :

```
   select Transaction_ID, 'A' as Product_Category,
       Incentive_On_A from Incentives
Union all
   select Transaction_ID, 'B' as Product_Category,
       Incentive_On_B from Incentives
Union all
   select Transaction_ID, 'C' as Product_Category,
       Incentive_On_C from Incentives
```

Is there any way I can optimize this query by removing union all with join?
Thanks alot for the help.

Edited**
1.Added one more row in both the tables.
Note:- Basically we are just doing a transpose of data - converting columns- 'Incentive_on_A','Incentive_on_B','Incentive_on_C' to a column - 'Category' having the values of the above 3 columns.

Comment: That's a strange data model. So a product can have a shirt price and a jeans price and a shorts price? What kind of product would that be? Weird. On first glance I'd say change this data model; it doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: 20 minutes for a simple union all query is also weird by the way. Did you mean seconds? `UNION ALL` is rather fast and there is nothing complicated about your query. How many records are in the table?

Comment: So, for every latest fashion in the market, you are going to add a new column to your Clothes table?

Comment: Hi Thorsten, thanks for your time. Actually In my project I have similar scenario with different tables and data. I took the products as an example to simplify the question. I am using union all 7 times to hit the same table and extract the product prices present in different columns into one column along with the hard coded values for cloth_type.

Comment: @KaushikNayak: we have predefined set of 7 fashion types which will always remain the same.

Comment: Although NOMB , I would be delighted to know the other 4 types which you offer?

Comment: But what does a record in the table represent? A set of clothes you sell together? Or is it a kind of data warehouse table showing sums of a day or the like? Why else would a record have two or more prices at the same time? Maybe you over-simplified your example too much, so that it is all obfuscated now.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner : Appogies for the confusion . I will rewrite the question to make it sound more logical .

Comment: Okay. So the table contains transactions. In your example there is always only one incentive per record. Is this so in your real data, too? In your example there is also not one incentive used twice. This means for three incentives there is a maximum of three rows. This is probably different from your real data, correct? And don't you want to show the transaction ID in your results? How else would you know what A = 30 refers to? Please add more records to your example to make these things clear.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner
I have edited the question. added one more record.hope it helps
One incentive per record in real data:- Yes, per transaction id.
One incentive can be used twice for another transaction/record.Yes

Answer (score 0):

To start with: this is a bad datamodel. If each record can only have one value, then just store one value, exactly as shown in your desired output.

As is, you can just add all values and use `CASE WHEN` to see which value is greater than zero:

```
select
  transaction_id,
  case when incentive_on_a > 0 then 'A'
       when incentive_on_b > 0 then 'B'
       when incentive_on_c > 0 then 'C'
  end as product_category,
  incentive_on_a + incentive_on_b + incentive_on_c as incentive_amt
from incentives
order by transaction_id;
```

(However, I still fail to see how such simple query like the one you are showing can run twenty minutes.)

Comment: `COALESCE()` isn't going to do what you want here, there are non-null values of 0 that the OP appears not to want.

Comment: @David Faber: Thank you. I had nulls in mind, but it's zeros. I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `JOIN` here, you just need to unpivot your data:

```
SELECT transaction_id, REGEXP_SUBSTR(incentive_col, '[^_]*$') AS product_category
     , incentive_amt
  FROM (
    SELECT transaction_id, incentive_a, incentive_b, incentive_c
      FROM incentives
) UNPIVOT (
    incentive_amt 
      FOR incentive_col IN (incentive_a, incentive_b, incentive_c )
) WHERE incentive_amt > 0;
```

Whether or not this will actually improve your performance, I could not say. My guess is that with the `UNION ALL` version of your query you're actually doing a full table scan 3 times.